# Django tutorial error part3

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Mpq.png)
I have a problem that I am working on Django tutorial and I want to take it in my browser at /polls/34/ but I don't know how to do that
It will refuse from localhost when I try to put in browser

I use python3 and django 2.0

Django tutorial gave this
Take a look in your browser, at “/polls/34/”. It’ll run the detail() method and display whatever ID you provide in the URL. Try “/polls/34/results/” and “/polls/34/vote/” too – these will display the placeholder results and voting pages

but I can't load that

Please Suugests and check below code

mysite/urls.py

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

mysite/polls/urls.py

```html
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

mysite/polls/views.py

```html
from django.http import HttpResponse

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

Comment: can you show full traceback, what error you have

Comment: I just attached a picture in the body

Comment: I input localhost/polls/34 but The browser responded as follows Not Found The requested URL /polls/34/ was not found on this serve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the URL I see that you haven't mentioned your URL properly. When you start your server through your command prompt with `python manage.py runserver` you could see a few series of output statements one of them is your starting development server at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to that you add your intended URL in your case should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/34/` will run you method you have connected to.

**Note**: In your case, your internal server might be different.

Comment: Thank you for your help 
I was able to solve the problem thanks to you!!
Thank you so much !!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

in your picture you go to `polls/34` but you need to type the address also
if you do all right from [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) access

```
http://localhost:8000/polls/34/
```

Answer (score 0):

In the URL you should give

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/**

and the o/p visible is "You are looking at question 1."

or 
**http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/34/**

and the o/p visible is "You are looking at question 34."